# Why is my else/if statement not working?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am stuck as to why my if/else statement is not working as it should. When I run the code, I have it add one to the money total if the image is coal.png, and it's supposed to add 6 if the image is sapphire.png but for some reason it still only adds 1.

Code block with my else/if statement:

```
<script> /* When an image is clicked, money is added to the counter */
$(function() {
$('#images').click(function() {
    moneyCalc();
});

function moneyCalc() {
    var images = $("#images");
    var money = parseInt($("#Money").text());

    if(images = "coal") {
        money = isNaN(money) ? 0: ++money;
    }
    else if(images = "sapphire") {
        money = isNaN(money) ? 0: money + 6;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    $("#Money").text(money);
}

function resetCounter() {
    $("#Money").text(0);
    }
});
</script>
```

Images code:

```
<div id="images">
        <img id="coal" src="coal.png">
        <img id="sapphire" src="sapphire.png" hidden="true">
</div>
```

I know my sapphire image is hidden, I have it appear in my code when I click a button after getting $50.

EDIT: For some reason it does not like when I have the sapphire image hidden and then I replace the coal with it. I removed the hidden="true" and when I clicked the sapphire it added 6. Now I have the issue of how to hide the sapphire without it messing up the code.

Comment: `=` is not for comparison. `==` and `===` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to make your code work:

- Used `===` (a comparison operator) instead of `=` (which is only for assignment)
- Put the click listener on the images themselves, and get the image name from the clicked image (rather than `$("#images")` which has no concept of which image you just clicked)
- Replaced `++money` with `money + 1` (incrementing the variable as well as reassigning it just sounds like trouble, although it may technically work)
- [There is no guarantee that `parseInt` will use decimal (base 10) – always provide the base as the second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#images img').click(function() {
        var imageName = $(this).attr("id");
        moneyCalc(imageName);
    });

    function moneyCalc(imageName) {
        var money = parseInt($("#Money").text(), 10);

        if(imageName === "coal") {
            money = isNaN(money) ? 0 : money + 1;
        } else if(imageName === "sapphire") {
            money = isNaN(money) ? 0 : money + 6;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        $("#Money").text(money);
    }

    function resetCounter() {
        $("#Money").text(0);
    }
});
</script>
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pk1ufxxf/)

Comment: This likely won't work. `$(this).attr("id")` will always return `images`.

Comment: Thanks. Typo, event listener should've been on `$('#images img')` not `$('#images')`.

Comment: This does the exact same thing as my original code, the sapphire does not add 6, it only adds 1.

Comment: @Cosmicluck You can see it adding 6 here http://jsfiddle.net/pk1ufxxf/ – if it's not working for you, something in your code is different to what's been posted here...

Comment: @Shai I made an edit to my post, I removed the hidden="true" on the sapphire and it adds 6 like it should. However I don't know how to make it replace the coal when I want it, and be hidden without breaking my code

Comment: @Cosmicluck I've added a `$("#coal").attr("hidden", "true")` to hide the coal, and a `$("#sapphire").removeAttr("hidden")` to unhide the sapphire, and the adding-6 still works: http://jsfiddle.net/pk1ufxxf/1/ . How are you doing your showing and hiding? I think upvote/mark any answers that helped you, then start a new question about the showing/hiding problem.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript comparisons use double equals `==` not single `=` (which defines)

```
[..]
if(images == "coal") {
    money = isNaN(money) ? 0: ++money;
}
else if(images == "sapphire") {
    money = isNaN(money) ? 0: money + 6;
}
else {
    return false;
}
[..]
```

An update based on your comment:

```
<script> /* When an image is clicked, money is added to the counter */
$(function() {
$('#images img').click(function() {
    moneyCalc( $(this).attr('id') );
});

function moneyCalc( images ) {
    var money = parseInt($("#Money").text());

    if(images == "coal") {
        money = isNaN(money) ? 0: ++money;
    }
    else if(images == "sapphire") {
        money = isNaN(money) ? 0: money + 6;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    $("#Money").text(money);
}

function resetCounter() {
    $("#Money").text(0);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Better off using [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) unless you explicitly need `==`.

Comment: Yes, true, but that's a conversation for another day ;) He's not likely to have differing data types here.

Comment: That just breaks my code, it works with the single = but it does not work if the image is sapphire, it still only adds 1 instead of the intended 6

Comment: Comparison does not work with a single `=`, believe me. You have a larger problem in your code. `var images = $("#images")` returns a DOM object, not a string. See the update above.